# Java - Equal spacing between texts

Tags: java, android

I have this list:

[image: List]

I have to put the text in a TextView with equal space beetween that 3 texts, like:

```
15/10/2015       +       Orale
17/10/2015       7½      Scritto/Grafico
20/11/2015       7       Orale
```

etc...

Obviously strings will splitted in the underscore and put in an array.
I have tried with the "\t" code but don't work, i also tried with [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964973/equal-spacing-in-enumerations)

but it also don't work, i think because of the different space occupied by texts even if they have the same number of characters. Anyone can help me?

Comment: What is the purpose of this format? Perhaps there is a better way than formatting with tabs

Comment: I need to have all 3 texts aligned as in the example

Comment: Yes.. but why, what are you doing with the texts

Comment: Why not use a tablelayout where you have each row with 3 columns and then align them as you want. giving the width required so each column is aligned

Comment: I was looking for an easier way, I don't always need a TableLayout

Answer (score -1):

[replace method?](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) will work if every char have same length (in pix)

```
String newString = oldStringWithOneLine.replace("_", "   ");
```

Comment: That won't correctly align texts that are not equal in length

Comment: true, nothing besides creating three `TextView`s in my mind... manual text measuring is pain in the...

Comment: The underscore it's a separator, i will do String[] tmp = string.split(underscore), so i will have all the words in the array, but i have to align them

Comment: yes, now Im understand, but don't have any idea besides creating three `TextView`s in e.g. horizontal `LinearLayout`. For fixed width of `TextView` you may set `layout_width` or `ems` ([setEms(int ems)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEms%28int%29)). you may also try using UTF character code for tab ("\u0009") instead of "\t"